# Angular 6 - open two dropdown in same thime

Tags: angular

i have the below, which contains two icons, each icon Opens a dropdown. When i click on any icon, the two dropdowns are opened at the same time.

```
                <div class="py-2">
                    <div class="dropdown float-right">
                        <span class="inner" data-target="search" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" ngbTooltip="Rechercher"><i
                                class="icons icon-search mx-2 my-1"></i></span>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right px-4 width-500" style="min-width: 400px;"
                            id="search">
                            <li>
                                <search-ef></search-ef>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <span class="inner" data-target="filter" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" ngbTooltip="Filter"><i
                                class="icons icon-slider_horizontal"></i></span>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right px-4 width-500" style="min-width: 400px;"
                            id="filter">
                            <li>
                                <filter-ef></filter-ef>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont usually use the ng-bootstrap dropdown but from your code I can infer that both dropdown have the same data-toggle.